# break table column to new line by media queries

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to know if I can break a table column to a new row if a specific media query is active.

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th class="column1"></th>
    <th class="column2"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

by default both `th` are next to each other. But I want `.column2` to break into a new line if a media query is triggered.

Any advice?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```css
table {
    width:100%;
    padding:0px 50px;
}
.column1 {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
}
.column2 {
    background:blue;
    height:50px;
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
    th {
        width:100%;
        display: block;
        margin:10px 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th class="column1"></th>
        <th class="column2"></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```